# Are qubits initialized in $|0\rangle$ by default in Stim?

Tags: stim

It is probably a silly question, but are qubits always initialized in  $|0\rangle$ when we implement circuits in Stim?

I am just using the [introduction tutorial](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/getting_started.ipynb), and it seems to be the case, given the outputs I get for the first examples. Yet, the example for the repetition code makes use of an $R$ gate right at the beginning of the circuit. This gate initializes qubits in  $|0\rangle$.

This is why I am confused: should we always use this $R$ gate at the beginning, or is it unnecessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they start in the $|0\rangle$ state. See the [semantics section of the stim circuit file format spec](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/file_format_stim_circuit.md#State-Space).

The reason I often include the reset gates is to make it unambiguous what the circuit will do, even for someone who doesn't know the initialization convention. Sort of ironic that making the circuit unambiguous makes the convention appear ambiguous.